On button Command, pass an ItemControl Item on a UserControl to the ViewModel
I think it's time to ask for help! I have an ItemsControl that lists UserControls (called CompoundCardControl):
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row = "1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Method.Compounds}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <control:CompoundCardControl/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>

The UserControl contains a button that is suppose to remove the item from the ListView (and the ViewModel):
<Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="RT"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding RetentionTime , StringFormat= '\{0\} minutes'}" />
    <Button Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource menuBarButton}"
            Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCompoundCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Compound}">
        <Image Width="12" Height="12"  Source="/Resources/Icons/Delete.png"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>

This is my ViewModel for my parent window (but it obviously doesn't work):
public class MethodDialogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //properties
    public DialogModeEnum DialogMode { get; private set; }
    public string WindowTitle { get { return DialogMode == DialogModeEnum.Add ? "New method" : "Edit method"; } }
    public string ButtonText { get { return DialogMode == DialogModeEnum.Add ? "Add" : "Update"; } }
    public Method Method { get; set; }
    public MethodCompound Compound { get; set; } = new MethodCompound();

    //constructor
    public MethodDialogViewModel(Method method, DialogModeEnum dialogMode)
    {
        DialogMode = dialogMode;    
        Method = method;
    }

    //commands
    public RelayCommand DeleteCompoundCommand => new(execute => DeleteCompound(Compound));
    private void DeleteCompound(MethodCompound methodCompound)
    {
        // Logic not implemented. I just want to see if I can get the object "methodCompound"
        if (methodCompound != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(methodCompound.ID);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a compound.", "Delete compound", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
    }
}

Basically I want to pass the Item (actually, the underlying object) in the ItemsControl to the ViewModel. How do I do that? Or am I totally botching this?

Seems to be a lot of "coupling" in the XAML when all you need is to get a "key" back to the data layer to do the lifting. An observable collection should be able signal the view of any deletes, etc.

There are some oddities with your code which appear to contribute to why nothing is working as expected.

The RelayCommand delegate seems to be wrong. Based on the parameter name execute it appears you get the delegate signature wrong. The original signature that the RelayCommand implements is ICommand.Execute(object commandParameter): void. This means the execute parameter of your lambda should be named e.g. commandParameter. Then you actually have to pass that parameter to the execute delegate. Otherwise, the Button.CommandParameter value will get lost i.e. not forwarded:
public RelayCommand DeleteCompoundCommand
=> new(commandParameter => DeleteCompound((MethodCompound )commandParameter));

The MethodDialogViewModel.Compound property always returns the same instance

The binding on Grid.Width inside the CompoundCardControl is redundant as Grid will naturally stretch to fill the available space.

Because you want to scroll the items inside the ItemsControl and not the ItemsControl itself, the ScrollViewer must be added to the ControlTemplate of the ItemsControl where it wraps the ItemsPresenter.
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
  <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
    <ScrollViewer>
      <ItemsPresenter />
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>


Note, the ItemsControl does not provide any performance features like UI virtualization which can significantly improve the experience for bigger lists or lists that hold expensive items or item containers.
ListBox on the other hand is an advanced ItemsControl that comes with scrolling and
with UI virtualization and some useful attributes like a ListBox.SelectedItem property that returns the currently selected item. In your case, you could bind it to the MethodDialogViewModel.Compound property. To get rid of the highlighting you simply have to override the ListBoxItem.Template:
<!-- 
  A ListBoxItem without highlighting. 
  You can add this template to a resource to reuse it. 
-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NoHighlightListBoxItemTemplate"
                 TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
    <ContentPresenter />
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>


Some general remarks: a custom control (e.g. a UserControl) should never use its own DataContext. For example, when the DataContext changes the control becomes broken. And because of the Binding.RelativeSource that target elements outside the custom control, moving the custom control to a different location in the visual tree will also break the custom control. To prevent that, add dependency properties that request the required data to be passed to the custom control e.g. via data binding. Then bind the internal controls to those dependency properties. It's not clear why you use a UserControl in this scenario. You can safely avoid the overhead of the UserControl by defining the layout of the items directly in the DataTemplate. You can move the DataTemplate to its own file if you need that separation.
This is not relevant to fixing your problem but it is if you care about good control design. These are some basics.


CompoundCardControl.xaml.cs
public partial class CompoundCardControl : UserControl
{
  public MethodCompound Compound
  {
    get => (MethodCompound)GetValue(CompoundProperty);
    set => SetValue(CompoundProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty CompoundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Compound",
    typeof(MethodCompound),
    typeof(CompoundCardControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public ICommand DeleteCommand
  {
    get => (ICommand)GetValue(DeleteCommandProperty);
    set => SetValue(DeleteCommandProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty DeleteCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DeleteCommand", 
    typeof(ICommand), 
    typeof(CompoundCardControl), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public CompoundCardControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}

CompoundCardControl.xaml
<UserControl x:Name="Root"> 
  <Button Style="{StaticResource menuBarButton}"
          Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DeleteCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Compound}">
    <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/Delete.png"/>
  </Button>
</UserControl>

MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MethodDialogViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>

    <!-- A ListBoxItem without highlighting -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="NoHighlightListBoxItemTemplate"
                     TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <ContentPresenter />
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Method.Compounds}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template" 
                Value="{StaticResource NoHighlightListBoxItemTemplate}" />
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MethodCompound}">
        <control:CompoundCardControl Command="{Biding DeleteCompoundCommand}"
                                     Compound="{Binding}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>

MethodDialogViewModel.cs
public class MethodDialogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  //properties
  public DialogModeEnum DialogMode { get; private set; }
  public string WindowTitle { get { return DialogMode == DialogModeEnum.Add ? "New method" : "Edit method"; } }
  public string ButtonText { get { return DialogMode == DialogModeEnum.Add ? "Add" : "Update"; } }
  public Method Method { get; set; }

  // This does never change. Consider to bind it to the ListBox.SelectedItem property
  public MethodCompound Compound { get; set; } = new MethodCompound();

  //constructor
  public MethodDialogViewModel(Method method, DialogModeEnum dialogMode)
  {
    DialogMode = dialogMode;
    Method = method;
  }

  //commands
  public RelayCommand DeleteCompoundCommand => new(ExecuteDeleteCompoundCommand);

  private void ExecuteDeleteCompoundCommand(object commandParameter)
    => DeleteCompound((MethodCompound)commandParameter);

  private void DeleteCompound(MethodCompound methodCompound)
  {
    // methodCompund will never be NULL in the current scenario

    this.Method.Compunds.Remove(methodCompound);
  }
}


I am always surprised by the generosity of people like you (probably a poor reflection on me). Thank you for the time you took to answer, explain, and correct my code. As you can guess, I’m struggling to understand the whole mvvm business. I’ve yet to implement your suggestions, but I felt I just needed to say that. Anyways, thank you.

Thank you very much for your appreciation. The way you honor my efforts is very kind. This makes me even more happy to help. Feel free to come back if you need assistance.

So I took your advice and and dumped the UserControl (not sure what I was thinking) and just used the DataTemplate in a ListBox (rather than a ItemsControl). Styling the ItemContainerStyle as you suggested, gave me the look I wanted.  Your code examples helped me a lot in understanding DPs and how to use them at some point in future - so thank you.  I got it to mostly to work using the SelectedItem property of the ListBox. Much simpler!

However, there are so many things I don't understand - LOL.  Specifically this.Method.Compounds.Remove(SelectedCompound) does not remove the item. But I'll post a new question about this. You're awesome.

Make sure the SelectedItem value is actually an item of the collection and make sure that this collection is an ObservableCollection that is bound to the ItemsSourcce. This way modifying the collection will be reflected in the ListBox.

Stupid mistake on my part. I had the 'List' property in the VM set with only a getter (with the data returned from a DB). Using properties as two-way channel to the UI is something new to me (yeah, I know that's the whole point - ha!). Up until I started using the mvvm pattern, I just loaded everything directly from a DB into a DataTable. Sigh. As always, much appreciated.

You should not use a List as binding source. Only IColletionChanged implementations like the ObservableCollection. Then you don't have to replace the collection to update changes in the UI which is very expensive in terms of performance.
